# How to back up iPhone / iPad without PC or iCloud?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud, backup

Are there ways besides iCloud or using a computer with iTunes to back up data on your iPhone or iPad?
One way seems to be a USB flash drive with a lightning connector... But is that just for photos and not other data like internet bookmarks, notes, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say… No.

The backup structure would require some kind of 'smart' object at the other end.
You cannot just connect a storage medium & push data to it. It is just not designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option I can think of would be [iMazing](https://imazing.com/features/backup-iphone-ipad). It will do backups and a whole lot more without jail breaking your iOS device.